# a string prints it content in one point correct and in another point wrong, there was no change

Tags: c, split, substring, c-strings, function-definition

this code was written for the only purpose of separating a string that looks like this "operand1 , operand2" , it puts each part in the data struct , i written puts() to check the content and the result is next to each line, i do not know why there is a difference, what can be wrong?

```
#define MAX_ROW_LEN 81
typedef struct parameters {
  char *first;
  char *second;
} param;

param separate(char *str) {
  char one[MAX_ROW_LEN] = {0}, two[MAX_ROW_LEN] = {0};
  param operands = {NULL, NULL};
  int i = 0;

  /*if first operand exists*/
  if (str != NULL) {
    while (*str != ' ') {
      one[i] = *str;
      str++;
      i++;
    }
    operands.first = one;
    puts(one);
    puts(operands.first); /*result : [r4] in both , correct*/
  }

  /*if second operand exists*/
  if (str != NULL) {
    /*remove the [ , ] between operands, if exists*/
    str++;
    str++;
    str++;
    i = 0;
    while (*str != '\0') {
      two[i] = *str;
      str++;
      i++;
    }
    operands.second = two;
    puts(two);
    puts(operands.second); /*result : [r6] in both , correct*/
  }
  return operands;
}
int main() {
  char *str = "r4 , r6";
  param op = separate(str);
  printf(" one = |%s|, two = |%s|\n", op.first, op.second);
  /*result is [ one = |???|, two = |r6|] why now it is ???? and not r4*/
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behavior. You're storage of `operands.first = one;` and `operands.second = two;` retains addresses of *local* automatic buffers `one` and `two` in the `separate` function. Returning out of that function expires those buffers, leaving the pointers to said-same now dangling. Back in `main` you then reference these addresses. E.g. *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

The function invokes undefined behavior because it sets data members of an object of the type `param` to addresses of local arrays that will not be alive after exiting the function.

So after exiting the function the data members of the object are invalid pointers.

You need dynamically to allocate character arrays where you will copy substrings of the passed string.

Pay attention to that you could easy determine the position of the comma by using the standard function `strchr`.

Comment: hii thank you for your answer, i got it working , however when i call on the function from another function its sends a null ? thats what i call:
char *trimed = (char *) malloc(MAX_ROW_LEN);
if(!trimed){error msg & exit}
trimed = Trim(token, RC);/*does something on the string works great*/
puts(trimed);/*prints the right string , everything is correct*/ 
param paramet = separate(trimed);    /*in the code i addesd put(str); and its "" and not the correct string*/
printf(" one = |%s|, two = |%s|\n", paramet.first,paramet.second);/*its both null cause the string was "" */
any idea why?

Comment: @user15244085 Show how the function is declared and how it is called.